# How can I specify what numbers should an array accept from a scanner

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean isArrayInputStillGoing = true;
    while (isArrayInputStillGoing){
    System.out.println("Please enter the size of the array");
    int sizeOfArray = input.nextInt();
    if (sizeOfArray < 0){
        System.err.println("Array cannot have a negative value try again");
        continue;
    }
    int[] initialArray = new int[sizeOfArray];
    System.out.println("Please enter the array elements");
    for (int i=0;i<sizeOfArray;i++){
        initialArray[i] = input.nextInt();
        if (initialArray[i] <= 0 || initialArray[i] > 100){
            System.out.println("Try again with a number between 1 and 100");
            continue;
        }
    }
    isArrayInputStillGoing = false;
        renderArray(initialArray);
    }
}
```

How can I make it so when a number less than 1 or more than 100 is inputed it requiers you to input that same number again. As is it just prints out the message and then prints the array with any inputed numbers even if they are wrong. Also it is saying that the continue is unneccesary since it is the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting the values in the array when the wrong number is sent to the array you continue in which the for loop increment the i counter then again new array is initialised just write i-- in the if block and you are all set also remove continue

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isArrayInputStillGoing = true;
        while (isArrayInputStillGoing){
        System.out.println("Please enter the size of the array");
        int sizeOfArray = input.nextInt();
        if (sizeOfArray < 0){
            System.err.println("Array cannot have a negative value try again");
            continue;
        }
        int[] initialArray = new int[sizeOfArray];
        System.out.println("Please enter the array elements");
        for (int i=0;i<sizeOfArray;i++){
            initialArray[i] = input.nextInt();
            if (initialArray[i] <= 0 || initialArray[i] > 100){
                System.out.println("Try again with a number between 1 and 100");
                i--;

            }
        }
        isArrayInputStillGoing = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning `input.nextInt()` to the array at position `i` in `initialArray[i] = input.nextInt();` you could first assign it to some candidate that you are going to test. You can achieve this by e.g. replacing the for loop as follows:

```
      System.out.println("Please enter the array elements");
      int i = 0;
      while (i < sizeOfArray) {

        int candidate = input.nextInt();

        if (candidate <= 0 || candidate > 100){
          System.out.println("Try again with a number between 1 and 100");
        } else {
          initialArray[i] = candidate;
          i++;
        }
      }
```